# In Bgp TTL security all control packets will have configured hop value?

Tags: ip, bgp, ttl

Topology:

`loop(2.1.1.1) - routerA (192.168.1.2)--------- (192.168.1.1) routerB - loop(1.1.1.1)`

I have eBGP peering configured with a Multihop of 2 on both sides and static routes to reach loopbacks.

- In the initial TCP handshake (SYN) from 1.1.1.1, the TTL is 2.
- Return SYN-ACK from peer 2.1.1.1 contains a TTL value of 255.
- All further BGP packets in both directions contain a TTL of 2.

Why do we see a TTL value of 255 in the SYN-ACK but a value of 2 in the other communication?

Edit:

R2

```
router bgp 200 
no synchronization 
bgp log-neighbor-changes 
neighbor 2.1.1.1 remote-as 100 
neighbor 2.1.1.1 ebgp-multihop 2 
neighbor 2.1.1.1 update-source Loopback1 
no auto-summary
```

R1

```
router bgp 100 
no synchronization 
bgp log-neighbor-changes 
neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 200 
neighbor 1.1.1.1 ebgp-multihop 2 
neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback1 
no auto-summary
```

Comment: Are you setting TTL Security on your neighbour statement? If so, can you share the config.

Comment: R2
router bgp 200
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 2.1.1.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 2.1.1.1 ebgp-multihop 2
 neighbor 2.1.1.1 update-source Loopback1
 no auto-summary

R1

router bgp 100
 no synchronization
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 remote-as 200
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 ebgp-multihop 2
 neighbor 1.1.1.1 update-source Loopback1
 no auto-summary

Comment: Please edit you post to add your configuration, using the preformatted option.

Comment: My guess: the 3-way handshake SYN -> SYN+ACK -> ACK is handled completely within the TCP stack. The application (BGP in this case) only gets an incoming connection on the TCP socket when the 3-way handshake has been completed. So, most likely, in the implementation the correct TTL is only set when after BGP code gets involved. It is possible to avoid this issue, but it involves changing the socket API.